# Show blank space in li tag

Tags: html, css

I have below HTML code

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li> </li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

I am expecting results like below

> ABC E

but instead, I am getting like

> ABCE

I cannot use `&nbsp;` as in my work I am iterating an array which might be something like below

```
array = ['A', 'B', 'C', ' ', 'E'];
```

Could someone please suggest how to get the whitespace for blank value?

here is the code pen https://codepen.io/gs650x/pen/mdmWOMJ

Comment: _"I cannot use &nbsp; as in my work I am iterating an array"_ - why do you think this is a reason you cannot use `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: Please do not add "codepen"s ... all _relevant_ code should be in the question as (code-formatted) text.

Comment: I am iterating an array, where would I mention &nbsp, there is only one li tag, how would I know, which one would be blank?

Comment: @Fildor all the code is mentioned in the question it self

Comment: ? Check the item length during iteration?

Comment: It is the one, where you only have whitespace or empty in your array item ... or you fix it in css, even.

Comment: for blank array element, I want whitespace on html

Comment: @Squiggs. the problem is not the blank array, problem blank array element

Comment: _"for blank array element, I want whitespace on html"_ - And since html renderers optimize whitespace by default, you have these two options: 1. Force space by CSS, 2. Add `&nbsp;` in script on empty array-item.

Comment: why do I deserve -1, what did I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space:pre`

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 80px;
    white-space:pre
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li> </li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the right solution if you are looking for the **exact width of the white-space** and not the width of the character.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `min-width: 1ch` where `1ch` means *width of 1 character*.

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 80px;
    min-width: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li> </li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

> **ch**
> Represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph "0" (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's font.
>
> Source:  [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a default width:

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    width: 20%;
    list-style: none;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li> </li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the width will not work, as I don't know the size of array element, it could be n number of characters

Comment: No sir, jax-p's answer is all I needed.

Comment: @gs650x Ok. You can set a minimum width to any value from 1px to 1%. But to make it really dynamic you will have to alter using javascript, otherwise it is still a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

to bring in some space between the letters you can try below code...

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 80px;
}

#downshow{
visibility: hidden;
}

<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li id="dontshow">D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

As per above code you have to type in some letters to the extent you need space and then in css styles you can make the visibility as hidden.